# animate with a Trigger button

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I have a `div` which extends its height on click. The jQuery code looks like this:

```
$('.contact-click').click(function() {
    $('#rollout').animate({
        height: "375", 
    }, 500);
});

$('a.close').click(function() {
    $('#rollout').animate({
        height: "0", 
    }, 500);
});
```

I would like to have a trigger button and not an `a` button for opening and closing the `div`. But I don't understand how to do this. For the `slide()` function there is a trigger option but not for animate. Why?
Thank you for your help

Comment: What do you mean `For the slide() function there is a trigger option`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or you culd just ues one button and use toggle.
Example:

```
<input type="button" id="triggerMe" value="Open/Close" />
```

And use toggle like so:

```
$('#triggerMe').toggle(function(){
    $('#rollout').animate({
        height: "375", 
    }, 500);
  },function(){
    $('#rollout').animate({
        height: "0", 
    }, 500);
  }
);
```

http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

Over n Out!
**Edit** example here http://jsfiddle.net/Xq63U/

Comment: Yes. Thank you very much. That's what I was searching for. I didn't see that I can use trigger instead of click. Thank you and everyone else for your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood your question, to have an HTML `button` click run the above code, you simply need to remove the `a` from the `close` selector:

```
$('.close').click(function() {
```

Then you need to put two buttons in your HTML, with the relevant classes as defined in your jQuery:

```
<input type="button" class="close" value="Close" />
<input type="button" class="contact-click" value="Contact" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="Button" onClick="$('.contact-click').trigger('click');" value="Animate"/>
    /*
    Will call 
    $('.contact-click').click(function() {
        $('#rollout').animate({
            height: "375", 
        }, 500);
    });
    */
<input type="Button" onClick=" $('a.close').trigger('click');" value="Close"/>

    /*
    will call
    $('a.close').click(function() {
        $('#rollout').animate({
            height: "0", 
        }, 500);
    });
    */
```